# How to access the properties of an object inside an array?

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript variable unavailabledates that I have done a console.log on and I get an array of objects.

```
   [Object, Object, Object]
    0: Object
    fromDate: "2014-02-28"
    toDate: "2014-02-23"
    __proto__: Object
    1: Object
    fromDate: "2014-02-13"
    toDate: "2014-02-28"
    __proto__: Object
    2: Object
    fromDate: "2014-03-27"
    toDate: "2014-03-20"
    __proto__: Object
    length: 3
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

How can I access the properties for one of these objects? For example, how can I get the fromDate of Object number 1?

Comment: I guess by `object number 1`, he means the first object, which will be `arr[0].fromDate`

Comment: Well, in his output the objects are numbered, so I'm assuming he's referring to that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This output means that `unavailabledates` is an array that contains three objects.

Usually you can access a specific item by its index: `var date1 = unavailabledates[0];`

Now you could get the `fromDate` with `date1.fromDate`.

You can do this in one step with `unavailabledates[0].fromDate;`